\usepackage[<language>]{babel} or \babelprovide{<language>}? Why?
This guide for language selecting mechanism suggests the following:

The first one is:
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

It will load the old good Italian language definition file. This procedure is the preferred one in most languages where an ldf exists, but there are exceptions (for example, Arabic and Hebrew). In general, you should do this for European languages written in Latin and Cyrillic scripts, as well as for Vietnamese. For Greek, it may depend on your needs, and very often both methods will be fine. If you want modern and ancient Greek at the same time, the next one is usually better.

The question is "preferred" in which sense? I am using a latest TeX Live, LuaLaTeX, Unicode fonts and most of such modern methods. What kind of advantage will, say, \usepackage[english]{babel} have over \babelprovide{english}? Will the compilation be faster? Is english.ldf richer in information when compared to english.ini? Suppose, I am aiming at an all-modern, backwards-blind approach, is it still better to hold on to the ldf-way? I am not worried about the compilation load, nor much in love with the rapid compilation. I just want the best possible output. With this question, I would love to know about the current situation of the organisation of these language files.

Not a practical answer, yet, but some general considerations.
My aim was (and still is) to facilitate a seamless transition from the ldf-based model to a modern, genuinely multilingual model that adheres to international standards and integrates effortlessly with automated document generation systems. This objective influenced certain features, such as the ability to select a language in short texts without a declaration in the preamble, and the method by which the high-level interface to fontspec (ie, \babelfont) manages font loading.
The primary issue with ldf files is the mechanism was originally designed to alter the language of monolingual documents, rather than to support genuinely multilingual documents. However, its principal advantage lies in certain instances (such as with French, Russian, German, Spanish, and a few others), where they offer excellent typographical and stylistic adaptations, often supported or approved by local user groups.
In most languages, there are no practical differences between ldf files and ini files, except for details and the use of shorthands, which are absent in ini files.
The problem is this transition cannot occur in a 'big bang' manner, with a completely new release with everything done. I made this error in 2016 (see the graph here), so I decided to proceed gradually with continuous development. I understand your point and, in fact, I concur the result can still be somewhat chaotic. However, I found no alternative, and thanks to this approach, Babel now supports approximately 300 languages, with varying degrees of coverage, comprising about 40 scripts.
I understand some people prefer to use only ini files (see at this regard https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1362). I believe with certain adjustments, this can be suitable in many instances, and I plan to delve further into this matter.

Thanks for your comments. I wholeheartedly appreciate all your efforts and I, especially being a linguist, understand the complexity of the task at your hand. A big cheers to all the hard work and hoping to see babel be more and more inclusive in the future!

I take that as a 'yes' :-).

[On deleting an answer.] Or rather as ‘as you wish’ .

If you load a language with an ldf babel typically reports that it loads the ini too:
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for english
(babel)             from babel-en.ini. Reported on input line 11.

So you get both and the question is only if actually need the ldf too.
This depends on the language.
If you compare the content of english.ldf and babel-en.ini there is not so much difference regarding the data, both set date format, caption names, hyphenation. babel-en.ini is perhaps a bit more complete and up-to-date. Here I would say that you could use only the ini.
If you load ngerman only through the .ini you loose things. E.g. shorthands like "a do not work, so normally I would use the ldf.
With french the difference is much larger, you only need to look at the babel-french documentation to see that it defines lots of options and keys and french typography in the .ldf.  Normally you should use it.
On the other side there are ldf files which are unmaintained and basically broken like arabic (hebrew is imho better now) and such ldf you should better avoid.

Thank you so much for a detailed answer, if I remember correctly, the ini-way has german instead of ngerman, right?

\babelprovide{ngerman} works too, but as I said, I normally load (n)german through the ldf.

Okay, thanks. I will wait for some more answers. Usually Javier is also quite active here, so maybe they have something to say. Or else I will accept this answer.
